# Macbook pro getting overheating with external monitor

Tags: display, temperature

My macbook pro (13") is overheating when I connect an external monitor (27"). I understand it's a problem with the scaling and the GPU, but what are my options to prevent that? An external GPU? A docking station with its own power? I'd like to also get a second monitor, so I'd really appreciate if there is a known solution for this overheating situation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: “Overheating” means it’s crashing/shutting down due to it’s thermal protection kicking in to prevent damage.  A number of things will happen *before* this condition - so, can you better describe what you mean by “overheating?”. Is it just a temperature increase?

Comment: Also, which MacBook Pro do you have?  What version of macOS?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, it's not shutting down or anything but the temperatures rise in the red spectrum and the fans go crazy. I've read on many posts that "that's okay", but if there is a way I would really like to prevent those things from happening

Comment: The “red spectrum?”. Are you using an app like iStats to get this info?

Comment: @Allan pro 2017 and catalina 10.15.4

Comment: Still need a bit more on the model - is it a Touch bar model?  Does it have Integrated Graphics or a discrete GPU?  However, based on your symptoms, I’m betting it has the Iris graphics (integrated).

Comment: @Allan Without touch bar. GPU is Intel Iris Plus Graphics 640 integrated

Comment: See this answer I wrote for a related question:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/355188/119271